# CAML Query at a time how many OR Conditions we can use?

Tags: sharepoint-server, caml-query

I was retrieving data from sharepoint list. When my query was less that time no issues to display the data. But more than 300 or conditions invloved in that query exception is coming "value does not fall within the expected range"

```
 SPList olistLegal = oWeb.Lists.TryGetList("TestList");
                                        SPQuery LEoquery = new SPQuery();

                                        LEoquery.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>" + Legalentityname + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
                                        // SPListItemCollection oItemLegalentitycoll = olistLegal.GetItems(LEoquery);
                                        foreach (SPListItem oItemLegalentitycoll in olistLegal.GetItems(LEoquery))
                                        {
                                            string contractid = Convert.ToString(oItemLegalentitycoll["ContractID"]);
                                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(LegalEntityquery) == true)
                                            {
                                                LegalEntityquery = "<Eq><FieldRef Name='ContractID' /><Value Type='Text'>" + contractid + "</Value></Eq>";
                                            }

                                            else
                                            {
                                                LegalEntityquery = "<Or>" + LegalEntityquery + "<Eq><FieldRef Name='ContractID' /><Value Type='Text'>" + contractid + "</Value></Eq></Or>";
                                            }
                                        }
```

i was receiving this error in my webpart.

[image]

Comment: Follow link https://stackoverflow.com/a/15021983/2985930 and check if this solves your problem.

Comment: alternate way would be to use **In** operator instead of **Or** operator.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not allowed to put more than two conditions in one condition group (And | Or) you have to create an extra nested group.

Comment: Actually we don't have any conditions to use only these many times. we can use n times **OR condition** in caml Query but use it as **Nested Group**.